# How to make sure, that the request is made from the Rotating IPs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, ip

I am working on scrapy, where I am using a concept of Rotating IPs and randomly changing the UserAgents,
However, I am not sure if the request that is being made is from the Different IP, or from my local machine's IP?

What I tried to do is:

As every request passes through a middleware's "process_request(self, request, spider)" method,
I have made this  logic of randomly taking the Proxy IPs from the Free Proxy API, write it into a file, then
read the Random IPs from the file, append it to a list and take random IP from the list, and append it to meta with key 'http_proxy'.

Below is the logic, that I am currently using for rotating IPs:

```
    def process_request(self, request, spider):

            proxy_list = []
            with open(PROXY_LIST_PATH) as fp:
                while True:
                    line = fp.readline()
                    if not line:
                        break
                    proxy_list.append(line.strip().replace('"',''))

            time_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
            random_time_delay = random.choice(time_list)
            time.sleep(random_time_delay) 

            random_ip = random.choice(proxy_list)
            request.meta['http_proxy'] = random_ip
            #request.meta['proxy'] = random_ip
            print("\nHeaders:",request.headers)
            print("\nRandom Proxyyyyy - ",random_ip
```

I am not sure if Is it the correct way to set Random IP in meta as:

> request.meta['proxy'] = random_ip

should I use 'http_proxy, 'proxy'? , I have searched about it, but could not find a correct way to add IP in a request?

Is there any way to know, that every request that I make is from a specific Proxy IP and not from my local IP? If Yes, what is the correct way to Rotate IPs in scrapy ?

Comment: You test the code, by making and logging several requests to `https://api.ipify.org?format=json`. Unless you plan adding proxies on the fly, use a list instead on a text file.

Comment: `request.meta['proxy'] = random_ip` is correct, I have been doing this for years :)

Answer (score 0):

To check the IP with which servers associate your requests, send a few requests to https://httpbin.org/ip and check the IP from the response.